# Is there a quicker way to search pandas column against list and read file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe called df1 with lots of rows:

```
AA    ID      info
H5R   SSF43   up
V53P  FG46Z   up
X1M   HJ44-2  down
P324N 2HUVG   up
L2F   SSF43   down
G223J FG46Z   up
```

and a list containing many file names:

```
['SSF43_354635.csv', 'HJ44-2_GF6453.csv', 'FG46Z_45362.csv', '2HUVG_223IU.csv', 
'SSF43_00202E.csv', 'FG46Z_01873GF.csv']
```

I'm looking for a quicker way to look through the ID column and if the ID occurs in any file name, read the files and look for the value in the AA column.

I have tried this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('data_info.csv', sep = '\t') 
file_names = [i for i in listdir('/content/data_files') if isfile(join('/content/data_files', i))]

df1["In_List"] = np.where(df1["ID"].isin([i.split('_', 1)[0] for i in file_names]), "True", "False")


# This part is slowing me down as it takes too long to run

for i in df1.iloc[:,1]:
  if i in [i.split('_', 1)[0] for i in file_names]:
# DO Something
```

Comment: make a dict of file names where key is the part before the _ and value is a list of all file names with that beginning,

Comment: Thanks, good idea, that helped a lot. Do you have any suggestions for matching each value in the AA column to its respective ID?  i.e. matching {'HJ44-2': ['HJ44-2_GF6453.csv']... } to X1M.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is the problem

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict as dd

f_names = ['SSF43_354635.csv', 'HJ44-2_GF6453.csv', 'FG46Z_45362.csv', '2HUVG_223IU.csv', 'SSF43_00202E.csv', 'FG46Z_01873GF.csv']
file_name_dict = dd(list)

for current_file_name in file_name:
    splited = current_file_name.split('_')
    file_name_dict[splited[0]].append(splited[1])



id_dict = dd(list)

#to avoid multiple use of df.loc, iterate one time and create a dict
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    id_dict[row['ID']].append(row['AA'])

for ID in file_name_dict:
    if ID not in id_dict:
        continue
    AA_set = set(id_dict['ID'])

    for currnet_fname in file_name_dict['ID']:
        tmp_df = pd.read_csv(currnet_fname)
        
        for index,row in tmp_df.iterrows():
            if row['column_name_you_need'] in AA_set:
                #do what you need
```

maybe its more officiant to look threw a file for all the values you want in a single file open

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code (which I have put below) but still am having trouble. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Still can't seem to solve this one.

```
tmp = df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(file_name_dict.keys())]

for index, row in tmp.iterrows():
  for fn in file_name_dict[row['ID']]:
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
      if row['AA'] in f:
        print(row)
```